# ARFoundation not working on split Android App Bundle

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, android-app-bundle

when we try to test our AR App using **AR Foundation** on Android via the Google Play Console it just does not work. The AR Content does not move relative to the camera. The app is bigger than 150MB so we have Player Settings>Publishing Settings>**Split Application Binary** = on. And we have to build as Android App Bundle for the Play Store. It works perfectly without splitting on device.
We saw this [article](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/arfoundation-samples/issues/96) where **splitting by architecture** seems to solve the problem. But since Google updated the rules, we have to upload an **AAB**. Not several APKs.
We're stuck. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

same here, apk from unity works fine, but the apk from google play console crash

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).